# Detecting Google map being closed and Google map infowindow being closed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to create a map dialog which allows the user to select his or her desired location.

I have a working example located at http://jsfiddle.net/HCUPa/1/, and the source code is below.

When the infowindow is closed (by clicking the X on the infowindow), how do I remove the associated marker?  Do I then need to remove the infowindows name from the array, and if so, how?

Also, when the map (or dialog and then the map) is closed, how do I detect it being closed, and should I be cleaning up any resources, and if so what and how?

I attempted to use addListeners for both as shown in my example, but it isn't working.

Lastly, not really my formal question, but I would appreciate any advise whether I am generally doing this correct.  This was my first attempt of the Google map api, and I am still a JavaScript novice, and would appreciate any suggestions, criticize, etc.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #googleMap { height: 100%;width: 100%;}
            div.modify-title-bar div.ui-dialog-titlebar {border:0;background-image:none;background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0;}
            #dialog-map,div.modify-title-bar {padding:0;margin:0;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function createMap(geocoder,myCenter,address) {

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),{center:myCenter,zoom:5,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myCenter,map: map,});

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<span>'+address+'</span><br><button class="accept">Select Address</button>'});
                infowindow.open(map,marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'close', function(event) {
                    //How do I detect map closing, what and how should I clean up?  Maybe move to dialog close?
                    alert('close map');
                    delete geocoder,myCenter,address,map,marker,infowindow;
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: event.latLng,
                        map: map,
                    });
                    geocoder.geocode({location: event.latLng}, function(GeocoderResult, GeocoderStatus) {
                        infowindow.close();
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<span>'+GeocoderResult[0].formatted_address+'</span><br><button class="accept">Select Address</button>'});
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
                        //How do I detect if infowindow is closed?  Do I then need to remove the infowindows name from the array, and if so, how?
                        alert('Remove marker');
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    });
                });
            }

            $(function(){
                $("#googleMap").on("click", "button.accept", function(){
                    $('#address').val($(this).parent().children('span').eq(0).text());
                    $("#dialog-map").dialog('close');
                });

                $("#findIt").click(function(){$("#dialog-map").dialog("open");return false;});
                $("#dialog-map").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 500,
                    width       : 800, 
                    modal       : true,
                    dialogClass : 'modify-title-bar',
                    open        : function() {
                        var address=$.trim($('#address').val()),
                        geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder,
                        LatLng,
                        //Default LatLng
                        Ya=47.6204901, Za=-122.34964839999998,
                        //Give default address to limit geocoder calls
                        default_address='400 Broad Street, Seattle, WA 98109, USA';
                        if(address) {
                            geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(GeocoderResult, GeocoderStatus) {
                                if (GeocoderStatus=='OK') {
                                    LatLng=GeocoderResult[0].geometry.location;
                                }
                                else {
                                    LatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(Ya,Za);
                                    adderss=default_address;
                                }
                                createMap(geocoder,LatLng,address);

                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            LatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(Ya,Za);
                            createMap(geocoder,LatLng,default_address);
                        }
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="findIt">Find it on a map</button>
        <input id="address" type="text" value="1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest Washington, DC">
        <div id="dialog-map" title="Select a location">
            <div id="googleMap"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new function that listens for the infowindow close event

```
function infowindowClose(infowindow, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
    });
}
```

Call that everytime you create a new infowindow.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HCUPa/7/)

You are doing well for your first time using the API.  If you want more than one marker and infobox then you will need to make a few changes, otherwise it's fine.

Comment: Thanks Seain,  Why is a separate function needed?  Does it relate to each infowindow being its own instance or something?  Also, is there really no need to delete the map after the dialog is closed?  Seems to work fine without doing so, but didn't know if it was good practice to do so.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1032531 There is no need to delete the map.  The reason for the function is just to save typing :)